# How to recover local work from a forced checkout?

Tags: git

I made changes in my local version of my fork. I realized my `HEAD` was detached so I committed and a made a branch '`temp`' with that commit. Wanting to put my local work onto the branch it should've been on '`feature`', I switched to '`feature`' and attempted `git merge temp`. Git refused to do so I tried to go back and did `git checkout temp`; however, my .`gitignore` file would be lost. I didn't really mind so I foolishly did `git checkout temp -f`. I am now on the `temp` branch again with the `HEAD` pointing to my most recent commit; however all my new files are gone. What can I do now?

I tried to checkout the commit and restore all my local changes but nothing has worked. It seems like edits I made to preexisting files are still around but all my new files that I began to track with the commit are gone.

> git merge temp
>
> > error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by 
> >       merge: *all my newly tracked files*
>
> git checkout temp
>
> > error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by 
> >       checkout:
> >             .gitignore
>
> git status
>
> > new files: *all my new files*
>
> git checkout temp -f
>
> git status
>
> > nothing to commit

:( pls help

Comment: It really looks like you *didn't* commit the files. Where was your `git commit` command?

Comment: See: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt---force

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the new files had been added to the index, right? If that's the case, to the best of my knowledge, those files had to be added (their contents) to git's object DB in order for them to have been in the index. If you care so much about them, at least the content is held inside the DB... now, how can you get the objects back? I hope this helps:

https://medium.com/@CarrieGuss/how-to-recover-from-a-git-hard-reset-b830b5e3f60c